# Kotlin: Камера фотографирует только на эмуляторе(Android 8) и некорректно отображает ссылки на фотографии в realtime database из Storage

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase, камера, storage

Пишу приложение в виде клона instagram (изучаю по урокам с YouTube, там создают на 8 андроиде, я пытаюсь сделать также только ещё и под 10 андроид), с Kotlin знаком всего пару недель. Очень много уже реализовал. Но именно с firebase возникают проблемы. Два вопроса:

1. Зарегистрировать пользователя в приложении и сохранить его текстовые данные в firebase - я могу с любого устройства. Через эмулятор на Android 8 - я могу сфотографировать и всё работает как нужно, даже корректно отображается ссылка на изменение фотографии профиля. Также есть файл ShareActivity, где пользователь может поделиться фотографией на "стене" и проблема в том, то что в google firebase в storage фотографии появляются, а в realtime database ссылка на эту фотографию записывается в виде `"com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask$TaskSnapshot@46529a6"`, а должна записываться в виде ссылки `"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/instapirate..."`, при этом фотография профиля отображается корректно, а именно посты - нет, фотографии просто не видно. Как исправить этот баг? Прикрепляю фотографию с эмулятора и базы данных:
   [image: Фотография с эмулятора]
   [image: Realtimedatabase]
   [image: Realtimedatabase2]
2. И ещё одна проблема, которая заключается в том, что на Android 8 в эмуляторе инстаграм у меня запросил разрешение на камеру, я разрешил и камера работает, фотографирует и всё происходит нормально. А в android 10 разрешение на камеру не запрашивается и, следовательно, камера открывается, фотографирует, но фотографии не может сохранить (переоткрывается при нажатии на кнопку "сохранить". Несколько раз если на кнопки потыкать быстро - иногда помогает сохранить фотографию, но это происходит в одном случае из миллиона. Не факт, что это связано именно с разрешением на камеру.

Код прикрепляю ниже:
`AndroidManifest`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.instapirate">


    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.INSTApirate" >

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.SearchActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.ShareActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.LikesActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.ProfileActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.EditProfileActivity"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.RegisterActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.ProfileSettingsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.AddFriendsActivity"/>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.instapirate.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Редактирование профиля происходит при помощи файла `EditProfileActivity`:
Конкретный кусок кода, который фотографирует и меняет аватарку пользователя, ссылка тут работает и загружается в Storage и в RealtimeDatabase в нормальном виде, но на Андроиде 10 фотография также не делается и камера сбрасывается:

```
    private lateinit var mUser: User
    private lateinit var mFirebase: FirebaseHelper
    private lateinit var mPendingUser: User
    private lateinit var mCamera: CameraHelper

    @SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == mCamera.REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mFirebase.uploadUserPhoto(mCamera.imageUri!!) {
                mFirebase.storageUid().addOnCompleteListener {
                    val photoUrl = it.result.toString()
                    mFirebase.updateUserPhoto(photoUrl){
                        mUser = mUser.copy(photo = photoUrl)
                        profile_image.loadUserPhoto(mUser.photo)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`loadUserPhoto` находится в отдельном файле `utils`, где хранятся все утилиты:

```
fun ImageView.loadUserPhoto(photoUrl: String?) =
    ifNotDestroyed {
        GlideApp.with(this).load(photoUrl).fallback(R.drawable.person).into(this)
    }
```

Вынесенные классы, которые участвуют в коде выше: `CameraHelper`

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Environment
import android.provider.MediaStore
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider
import java.io.File
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*

class CameraHelper(private val activity: Activity) {
    var imageUri: Uri? = null
    val REQUEST_CODE = 1
    private val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US)

    fun takeCameraPicture() {
        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        if (intent.resolveActivity(activity.packageManager) != null) {
            val imageFile = createImageFile()
            imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity,
                "com.example.instapirate.fileprovider",
                imageFile)
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri)
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)
        }
    }
    private fun createImageFile(): File {
        val storageDir = activity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        return File.createTempFile(
            "JPEG_${simpleDateFormat.format(Date())}_",
            ".jpg",
            storageDir
        )
    }
}
```

`FirebaseHelper`

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.net.Uri
import com.example.instapirate.activities.showToast
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask

class FirebaseHelper(private val activity: Activity) {
    val auth: FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    val database: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
    val storage: StorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference

    fun storageUid() = storage.child("users/${auth.currentUser!!.uid}/photo/").downloadUrl

    fun uploadUserPhoto(photo: Uri, onSuccess: (UploadTask.TaskSnapshot) -> Unit) {
        storage.child("users/${currentUid()!!}/photo").putFile(photo)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    onSuccess(it.result!!)
                } else {
                    activity.showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
                }
            }
    }

    fun updateUserPhoto(photoUrl: String, onSuccess: () -> Unit) {
        database.child("users/${currentUid()!!}/photo").setValue(photoUrl)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    onSuccess()
                } else {
                    activity.showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
                }
            }
    }

    fun updateUser(updates: Map<String, Any?>, onSuccess: () -> Unit) {
        database.child("users").child(currentUid()!!).updateChildren(updates)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    onSuccess()
                } else {
                    activity.showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
                }
            }
    }

    fun updateEmail(email: String, onSuccess: () -> Unit) {
        auth.currentUser!!.updateEmail(email).addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                onSuccess()
            } else {
                activity.showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
            }
        }
    }

    fun reauthenticate(credential: AuthCredential, onSuccess: () -> Unit) {
        auth.currentUser!!.reauthenticate(credential).addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                onSuccess()
            } else {
                activity.showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
            }
        }
    }

    fun currentUserReference(): DatabaseReference =
        database.child("users").child(currentUid()!!)

    fun currentUid(): String? =
        auth.currentUser?.uid

}
```

Также существует файл `ShareActivity`, который реализует загрузку фотографий на ленту, и вот тут появляются проблемы с Firebase, так как именно тут ссылки отображаются в некорректной форме(Скриншот ленты был выше), если фотография сделана на Android 8 (на Android 10 после сохранения фотографии камера переоткрывается и приходится заново фотографировать и так по кругу)

```
class ShareActivity : BaseActivity(2) {
    private val TAG = "ShareActivity"
    private lateinit var mCamera: CameraHelper
    private lateinit var mFirebase: FirebaseHelper
    private lateinit var mUser: User

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_share)
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate")

        mFirebase = FirebaseHelper(this)
        mCamera = CameraHelper(this)
        mCamera.takeCameraPicture()

        back_image.setOnClickListener{finish()}
        share_text.setOnClickListener{ share()}

        mFirebase.currentUserReference().addValueEventListener(ValueEventListenerAdapter{
            mUser = it.asUser()!!
        })
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == mCamera.REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                GlideApp.with(this).load(mCamera.imageUri).centerCrop().into(post_image)
            } else {
                finish()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun share() {
        val imageUri = mCamera. imageUri
        if (imageUri != null) {
            val uid = mFirebase.currentUid()!!
            mFirebase.storage.child("users").child(uid).child("images")
                .child(imageUri.lastPathSegment.toString()).putFile(imageUri).addOnCompleteListener{
                    if (it.isSuccessful){
                        val imageDownloadUrl = it.result!!.toString()
                        mFirebase.database.child("images").child(uid).push()
                            .setValue(imageDownloadUrl)
                            .addOnCompleteListener {
                                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                                    mFirebase.database.child("feed-posts").child(uid)
                                        .push()
                                        .setValue(mkFeedPost(uid, imageDownloadUrl))
                                        .addOnCompleteListener {
                                            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                                                startActivity(Intent(this,
                                                    ProfileActivity::class.java))
                                                finish()
                                            }
                                        }
                                } else {
                                    showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
                                }
                            }
                    } else {
                        showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    private fun mkFeedPost(uid: String, imageDownloadUrl: String): FeedPost {
        return FeedPost(
            uid = uid,
            username = mUser.username,
            image = imageDownloadUrl,
            caption = caption_input.text.toString(),
            photo = mUser.photo
        )
    }
}
```

При попытке сохранить фотографию на android 10 не через эмулятор, в Debug появляется следующий текст(всю ошибку запихнуть не получилось из-за ограничений, но думаю, что это важная часть ошибки):

```
2022-03-20 19:05:55.711 29351-29351/? I/ple.instapirat: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2022-03-20 19:05:55.855 29351-29351/? E/ple.instapirat: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2022-03-20 19:05:56.943 29351-29351/com.example.instapirate I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
2022-03-20 19:05:57.016 29351-29351/com.example.instapirate I/FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
2022-03-20 19:05:57.126 29351-29351/com.example.instapirate D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( PjHBujbeapTQxmLl4TgzhgOTzjo2 ).
2022-03-20 19:05:57.158 29351-29351/com.example.instapirate I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
2022-03-20 19:05:57.194 29351-29422/com.example.instapirate I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:69 and remote module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:67
2022-03-20 19:05:57.194 29351-29422/com.example.instapirate I/DynamiteModule: Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite
2022-03-20 19:05:57.263 29351-29424/com.example.instapirate E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.instapirate
2022-03-20 19:05:57.264 29351-29424/com.example.instapirate E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
2022-03-20 19:05:57.427 29351-29425/com.example.instapirate I/FA: App measurement initialized, version: 60000
2022-03-20 19:05:57.427 29351-29425/com.example.instapirate I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
2022-03-20 19:05:57.428 29351-29425/com.example.instapirate I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.instapirate
2022-03-20 19:05:57.428 29351-29425/com.example.instapirate D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
2022-03-20 19:05:57.554 29351-29351/com.example.instapirate W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@6dd3e0e
2022-03-20 19:05:57.825 29351-29351/com.example.instapirate W/ple.instapirat: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-03-20 19:05:57.827 29351-29351/com.example.instapirate W/ple.instapirat: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-03-20 19:05:58.076 29351-29351/com.example.instapirate D/ShareActivity: onCreate
2022-03-20 19:05:58.332 29351-29425/com.example.instapirate I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
2022-03-20 19:05:58.417 29351-29511/com.example.instapirate D/skia: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'
2022-03-20 19:05:58.441 29351-29511/com.example.instapirate D/skia: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'
2022-03-20 19:05:58.443 29351-29511/com.example.instapirate I/chatty: uid=10260(com.example.instapirate) glide-source-th identical 1 line
2022-03-20 19:05:58.444 29351-29511/com.example.instapirate D/skia: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'
2022-03-20 19:05:58.451 29351-29519/com.example.instapirate D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2022-03-20 19:05:58.467 29351-29511/com.example.instapirate D/skia: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'
2022-03-20 19:05:58.472 29351-29511/com.example.instapirate D/skia: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'
2022-03-20 19:05:58.571 29351-29439/com.example.instapirate I/AdrenoGLES: QUALCOMM build                   : 7331a27, Ieeb4a86f7b
    Build Date                       : 11/13/19
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.27.05.02
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Reconstruct Branch               : 
2022-03-20 19:05:58.571 29351-29439/com.example.instapirate I/AdrenoGLES: Build Config                     : S L 8.0.12 AArch64
2022-03-20 19:05:58.608 29351-29439/com.example.instapirate I/AdrenoGLES: PFP: 0x005ff113, ME: 0x005ff066
2022-03-20 19:05:58.618 29351-29439/com.example.instapirate W/AdrenoUtils: <ReadGpuID_from_sysfs:194>: Failed to open /sys/class/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/gpu_model
2022-03-20 19:05:58.618 29351-29439/com.example.instapirate W/AdrenoUtils: <ReadGpuID:218>: Failed to read chip ID from gpu_model. Fallback to use the GSL path
2022-03-20 19:05:58.668 29351-29439/com.example.instapirate W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
2022-03-20 19:05:58.751 29351-29351/com.example.instapirate W/Glide: Load failed for content://com.example.instapirate.fileprovider/images/JPEG_20220320_190558_2535596221289941323.jpg with size [204x204]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There were 3 causes:
    java.io.IOException(java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFEA)
    java.io.IOException(java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFEA)
    java.io.IOException(java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFEA)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 4): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{AutoCloseInputStream->Object->Drawable}, LOCAL
        Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{AutoCloseInputStream->GifDrawable->Drawable}
        Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{AutoCloseInputStream->Bitmap->Drawable}
        Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{AutoCloseInputStream->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
      Cause (2 of 4): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{ParcelFileDescriptorInner->Object->Drawable}, LOCAL
    There were 2 causes:
    java.io.IOException(java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFEA)
    java.io.IOException(java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFEA)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 2): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{ParcelFileDescriptorInner->Bitmap->Drawable}
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.IOException(java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFEA)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFEA
        Cause (2 of 2): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{ParcelFileDescriptorInner->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.IOException(java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFEA)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFEA
      Cause (3 of 4): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{AssetFileDescriptor->Object->Drawable}, LOCAL
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.IOException(java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFEA)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{AssetFileDescriptor->Bitmap->Drawable}
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.IOException(java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFEA)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFEA
      Cause (4 of 4): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{HierarchicalUri->Object->Drawable}, LOCAL
        Cause (1 of 2): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{HierarchicalUri->Drawable->Drawable}
        Cause (2 of 2): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{HierarchicalUri->Bitmap->Drawable}
2022-03-20 19:05:58.753 29351-29351/com.example.instapirate I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 3)
    java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFEA
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.VideoDecoder.decode(VideoDecoder.java:185)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodePath.decodeResourceWithList(DecodePath.java:92)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodePath.decodeResource(DecodePath.java:70)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodePath.decode(DecodePath.java:59)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.LoadPath.loadWithExceptionList(LoadPath.java:76)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.LoadPath.load(LoadPath.java:57)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runLoadPath(DecodeJob.java:524)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromFetcher(DecodeJob.java:488)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromData(DecodeJob.java:474)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromRetrievedData(DecodeJob.java:426)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherReady(DecodeJob.java:390)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.onDataReadyInternal(SourceGenerator.java:148)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator$1.onDataReady(SourceGenerator.java:76)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:52)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNextLoad(SourceGenerator.java:70)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromRetrievedData(DecodeJob.java:434)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherReady(DecodeJob.java:390)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.onDataReadyInternal(SourceGenerator.java:148)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator$1.onDataReady(SourceGenerator.java:76)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:52)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNextLoad(SourceGenerator.java:70)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:279)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:393)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFEA
        at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:142)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.VideoDecoder$ParcelFileDescriptorInitializer.initialize(VideoDecoder.java:306)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.VideoDecoder$ParcelFileDescriptorInitializer.initialize(VideoDecoder.java:301)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.VideoDecoder.decode(VideoDecoder.java:173)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodePath.decodeResourceWithList(DecodePath.java:92) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodePath.decodeResource(DecodePath.java:70) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodePath.decode(DecodePath.java:59) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.LoadPath.loadWithExceptionList(LoadPath.java:76) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.LoadPath.load(LoadPath.java:57) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runLoadPath(DecodeJob.java:524) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromFetcher(DecodeJob.java:488) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromData(DecodeJob.java:474)
```

Если потребуются ещё необходимые данные с кода, то я смогу отредактировать пост и добавить их (мне кажется и так слишком много кода прикрепил, извиняюсь, но он весь важен). Надеюсь, кто-нибудь сможет помочь мне решить хотя бы 1 проблему...

Comment: UPD: В эмуляторе на Android 10 камера работает. Возможно проблема связана именно с моим устройством физическим.

Comment: UPD 2: Да проблема с камерой была связана с конкретным устройством. Теперь актуален только первый вопрос, всё ещё не понимаю почему ссылки неправильно сохраняются в базу данных

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему. Фотографии отображаются корректно. Для этого я добавил в файл `FirebaseHelper` этот код:

```
    fun uploadSharePhoto(localPhotoUrl: Uri, onSuccess: (UploadTask.TaskSnapshot) -> Unit) =
        storage.child("users/${auth.currentUser!!.uid}").child("images")
            .child(localPhotoUrl.lastPathSegment!!)
            .putFile(localPhotoUrl)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful)
                    onSuccess(it.result!!)
                else
                    activity.showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
            }

    fun addSharePhoto(globalPhotoUrl: String, onSuccess: () -> Unit) =
        database.child("images").child(auth.currentUser!!.uid)
            .push().setValue(globalPhotoUrl)
            .addOnComplete { onSuccess() }

    private fun Task<Void>.addOnComplete(onSuccess: () -> Unit) {
        addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful)
                onSuccess()
            else
                activity.showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
        }
    }
```

и в `ShareActivity` функцию `share()` заменил на:

```
    private fun share() {
        val imageUri = mCamera.imageUri
        if (imageUri != null) {
            mFirebase.uploadSharePhoto(imageUri) {
                it.metadata!!.reference!!.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                    mFirebase.addSharePhoto(it.toString()) {
                        mFirebase.database.child("feed-posts").child(mFirebase.auth.currentUser!!.uid)
                            .push()
                            .setValue(mkFeedPost(mFirebase.auth.currentUser!!.uid, it.toString()))
                            .addOnCompleteListener {
                                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                                    startActivity(Intent(this,
                                        ProfileActivity::class.java))
                                    finish()
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```